# javascript - New to this thing

Tags: javascript

If I have 3 variables - My javascript:
How can I run through the variables in "for" loop?

```
var mesh_1;
var mesh_2;
var mesh_3;
for(var i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    mesh_+i = 10;
}
```

Any ideas???

Comment: I don't think `mesh_+i = 10;` is a valid statement.

Answer (score 2):

Ad it in an array:

```
var mesh = [];
for(var i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    mesh[i] = 10;
}
```

Now you can retrieve it like this:

```
alert(mesh[3]); // alerts 10 (of course)
```

Comment: And if this mesh is an object with properties??? For example my mesh is holding the position-x data---> mesh.position.x

Comment: that's a completely different question